# Recolor picture to black and white 75% using Word VBA

Tags: vba, image, ms-word

I have using below, in Word document.

```
Sub Recolor()

Dim pic As InlineShape
Dim shp As Shape

Set pic = Selection.InlineShapes(1)
Set shp = Selection.ShapeRange(1)

pic.PictureFormat.ColorType = msoPictureBlackAndWhite
shp.PictureFormat.ColorType = msoPictureBlackAndWhite

End Sub
```

That performs `Black and White 50%`

But I need `Black and White 75%`, How can coding **75%** Recolor?

Comment: Have you tried  adjusting the brightness and contrast  of the picture format ?

Comment: How can simulate the appropriated behavior of `Black and White 75%` with adjusting brightness and contrast in case of `Black and White 50%` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The VBA object model doesn't have hooks for all the color transformations that are in Word. The **75%** in the Black and White 75% refers to a color transformation parameter called **Threshold** in the XML. But Threshold is not available in VBA. Here's a macro that achieves a similar look by lowering brightness, increasing contrast and reducing saturation. You can play with the values and the command order, which makes a difference to the final appearance:

```
Sub Recolor()
    Dim pic As InlineShape

    Set pic = Selection.InlineShapes(1)
    With pic
        With .PictureFormat
            .Brightness = 0.24
            .Contrast = 1
        End With
        With .Fill.PictureEffects
            .Insert(msoEffectSaturation).EffectParameters(1).value = 0
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Great! Thank you so much.

Comment: How can made `Sharpen=50%` ?

Comment: What is equivalent `Contrast= -40%`?

Comment: You can keep the Format Picture pane open and rerun the macro with different values to find this out yourself. Format Picture will show when your macro creates the values you're asking about. `.Contrast = 0.3` will give you -40%, `.Fill.PictureEffects.Insert(msoEffectSharpenSoften).EffectParameters(1).value = 0.5` sharpens 50%